# Django ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique

Tags: django

### Question

How do I configure my app and label my application correctly so that I don't run into a `Application labels aren't unique` error and so that it works?

> I understand that I can rename auth. I do not wish to rename auth.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...,
   "core.auth",
   ...
]
```

```
$ python manage.py shell_plus
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 95, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth
```

---

I added the following:

**core/auth/**init**.py**

```
default_app_config = 'core.auth.AuthConfig'
```

**core/auth/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "core_auth"
    label = "core_auth"
    verbose_name = "Core Auth"
```

```
$ python manage.py shell_plus
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/stackoverflow/dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    if not issubclass(app_config_class, AppConfig):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application `name` and the application `label` are different things. Directly quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configurable-attributes):

The `AppConfig.name` is the:

> Full Python path to the application

and `AppConfig.label` is the

> Short name for the application

Furthermore it is also said about the `label` that

> This attribute allows relabeling an application when two applications
> have conflicting labels

Hence you want to only change the `label` and not change the `name`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "core.auth" # I assume it was this according to your shown INSTALLED_APPS, if not it should be what it originally was
    label = "core_auth"
    verbose_name = "Core Auth"
```

Also I believe instead of `default_app_config = 'core.auth.AuthConfig'` it should be `default_app_config = 'core.auth.apps.AuthConfig'` since you declare `AuthConfig` in the `apps.py` file.

Comment: Not setting `name` doesn't help.

Comment: @Vishal also is `core.auth` a _string_ in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? It seems you are missing the quotes?

Comment: @Vishal Also `default_app_config = 'core.auth.AuthConfig'` this seems incorrect? Shouldn't it be `default_app_config = 'core.auth.apps.AuthConfig'` as you declare that in the `apps.py` file?

Comment: Bingo. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Abdul. Could you help me with the same issue. Posted a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911506/django-3-2typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class